# Unable to get Const variable after creating an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, constants

Here is my c# class code

```
 public class ConstReadOnly
{
    public const int cV = 10;
    public readonly int rV = 40;
}
```

Now when i try to create an instance of this class i'm not getting the `const` variable `cV`.What may be the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` are implicitly static, you can access them through class name like:

```
ConstReadOnly.cV
```

You may see this post from Jon Skeet - [Why can't I use static and const together?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because constants are implictly static.

If you want to use them, use the class name as the qualifier.

```
 int fromConstInt = ConstReadOnly.cV;
```